# SSRS Report Builder - How to calculate the date diff and add IFF statement between 2 data sets

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder

I am trying to calculate the difference in days between 2 data sets and then if the value is between 1 and 2 days then it should show compliant if the value is a negative number or greater than 2 days I want it to show non-compliant. I am not sure what I have wrong, it runs however they all show compliant

Background on the calculation needed.
IMM Discharge compliance - Hospitals must
deliver a copy of the signed notice to each beneficiary not more than two (2) days before the day of discharge. Follow-up notice is not required if delivery of the initial IM falls within two (2)
calendar days of discharge.

FYI - the first IFF statement is because some do not have dates so that was to account for those

```
=IIF(
    IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Intervention_Date_Of_Service.Value, "Interventions")), 
    "No Intervention", 
    IIF(
        DateDiff("d",Fields!Actual_Discharge_Date.Value,Lookup(Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Account_Number.Value,Fields!Intervention_Date_Of_Service.Value, "Interventions")) <=2,
        "Compliant",
        "Non-compliant")
    )
```

I have tried multiple variations =1 or 2, etc if I use just the =2 they all show non-compliant

Comment: Are you sure that you want to subtract the `Actual_Discharge_Date` from the DOS? If the Discharge date is greater that the DOS, the result will be a negative number, which is `< = 2`. I think you need to swap those argument in the DateDiff, with the Discharge being the second date.

Answer (score 0):

You have two conditions for non-compliance - the difference being negative or greater than 2 days so you have to check both conditions. Try something like this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!Account_Number.Value, Fields!Account_Number.Value, Fields!Intervention_Date_Of_Service.Value, "Interventions")), 
    "No Intervention", 
    IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!Actual_Discharge_Date.Value, Lookup(Fields!Account_Number.Value, Fields!Account_Number.Value, Fields!Intervention_Date_Of_Service.Value, "Interventions")) < 1,
        "Non-compliant", 
        IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!Actual_Discharge_Date.Value, Lookup(Fields!Account_Number.Value, Fields!Account_Number.Value, Fields!Intervention_Date_Of_Service.Value, "Interventions")) > 2,
            "Non-compliant",
            "Compliant" 
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: This worked almost the only issue I am seeing is that if there are multiple interventions it is not looking at the most recent date

Comment: You'll need to get the maximum date for the `Lookup` dataset - `select Account_Number, MAX(Intervention_Date_Of_Service) from Interventions group by Account_Number`